# Android File Transfer

Tags: android

I installed the "Android File Transfer" to move some data. So far so good.

But there is one issue annoying me. Every time I connect my mobile via USB, the Mac changes to the main desktop and opens the "File Transfer" app.

**So, is there a possibility to bear it down?** I couldn't find any option to change it.
...the connection is not very stable, so every time I touch my mobile it dis- and reconnect and push the window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found Airdroid much easier and less temperamental to use in controlling/managing my android

http://www.airdroid.com

You will need app on your phone and browser bookmark

Answer (score 1):

[You can disable the auto start of Android File Transfer](https://cooltrainer.org/taming-android-file-transfer-on-mac-os-x/), and only open it in case you need it.

Here are the steps you need to do:

- Open up User & Groups and remove Android File Transfer from the Login Items
- remove the agent from Google's app's library: `rm -r ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Android\ File\ Transfer/Android\ File\ Transfer\ Agent.app`
- remove the backup agent from Google's app: `rm -r /Applications/Android\ File\ Transfer.app/Contents/Resources/Android\ File\ Transfer\ Agent.app`

The removing steps are needed, as otherwise the app will unfortunately reinstall itself to the login items the next time you start it. Also instead of removing, you can just move them away for backup in case you might need them.

After doing these steps the app will not start when you connect a phone, and you need to open it manually (<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> plus start typing "Android File Transfer") when required.